# Asynchronus mouse hook?

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to receive mouse events so was using SetWindowsHook and also tested Raw Input API. Both are great, but they are syncrhonus, in that I can return something to block it. Is there any API that gives it to me async, I need to not worry about blocking.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system won't provide you with an asynchronous mechanism to achieve this. You'll have to implement that yourself by queueing the events to yourself.

Comment: Thanks @David, may you please share code on how to do that, or maybe just a pointer to some links :)

Comment: I don't have any code to do that, and I don't know much about your target environment. You are usually coding inside FireFox add-ons IIRC so that very likely has implications.  You just need some form of asynchronous message passing, of which there are many many possible options.

Comment: Yep haha thanks you know me well from my incessant posting huh? :P I actually learned a whole bunch from you, Hans, and Remy, and I teach others from what I learned! :) Ok ill search on the subject :)

Comment: Yeah, good luck! And I'm flattered to be mentioned in the same sentence as Hans and Remy :-)

Comment: I thought you guys were contemporaries, just based on you guys all have some crazy hundred k score on stack :P But thanks I think that's the first thing I could do for you in your many months of helping me! Which makes me feel less of a bum for bumming solutions off you guys for so long hahahah

Comment: It might surprise you, but I'm here mostly to learn. I've learnt loads trying to figure out other people's problems!!